# Action on Google sign-in doesn't trigger intent after login

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a assistant app where some of the intents are only available after you do account linking. To be able to have a seamless onboarding when a intent is triggered that require sign-in the sign-in flow is triggered and after the intent is resolved.

I've used the sign-in helper and that works, but when the sign-in is done it gives a error message "Sorry, something went wrong, so I couldn't sign you in. But you can try again later."

If the app is triggered again the user is signed-in and everything works as it should.

I'm running the webhook as a firebase function

Any advice how I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

After the Sign-In helper completes, it sends an `actions_intent_SIGN_IN` event. You should capture this event in a Dialogflow Intent and then handle it in a handler for this event. The handler should call the same thing that the handler for the usual event would call.

Comment: That makes sense! Tanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer has helped you, accepting and/or upvoting it is always appreciated.

Comment: what's intent need to add in Dialogflow. I do just account linking in google Actions Console.